# how to change the signature algorithm of SAML request in spring security

Tags: java, spring, digital-signature, saml, spring-saml

I am using spring security saml extension to implement SSO with ADFS as IDP.

As I understand, spring security uses open saml to sign the SAML request with SHA1withRSA as signature algorithm.

We need to be change to sign the SAML request with SHA256withRSA instead.

how can this be done ?

Appreciate any suggestions on this. Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to use the latest Spring SAML (or at least update OpenSAML to the latest version). Extend the SAMLBootstrap class as below and plug it instead of the original SAMLBootstrap class in your Spring configuration:

```
package fi.schafer.saml.custom;

import org.opensaml.Configuration;
import org.opensaml.xml.security.BasicSecurityConfiguration;
import org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureConstants;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;

public class SAMLBootstrap extends org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap {

    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);

        BasicSecurityConfiguration config = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
        config.registerSignatureAlgorithmURI("RSA", SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
        config.setSignatureReferenceDigestMethod(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA256);

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make registerSignatureAlgorithmURI configurable?

Comment: There's a whole new implementation underway, I don't believe new features will be added to the current version.

Comment: I was reading your answer @VladimírSchäfer and was wondering if I am getting the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769788/the-security-strength-of-sha-1-digest-algorithm-is-not-sufficient-for-this-key-s for the same reason. I extended the SAMLBootstrap class but I am still getting it. I am not sure what is needed to chage the security strength of the digest algorithm. The strength now is 160 and should be greater of 224. I got that from the debug.